# Class 'ZipArchive' not found even with zip extension installed

Tags: php, php-extension

I know, there are a lot of questions asked about this error and I read them but it didn't help me.

I checked if the `zip` extension is installed and it does:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom

...

zip
zlib
```

I also checked the php.ini files loaded:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/bcmath.ini,
/etc/php.d/bz2.ini,
/etc/php.d/calendar.ini,
/etc/php.d/ctype.ini,
/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/exif.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/ftp.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/gettext.ini,
/etc/php.d/gmp.ini,
/etc/php.d/iconv.ini,
/etc/php.d/intl.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/posix.ini,
/etc/php.d/recode.ini,
/etc/php.d/shmop.ini,
/etc/php.d/simplexml.ini,
/etc/php.d/sockets.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/tidy.ini,
/etc/php.d/tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php.d/twig.ini,
/etc/php.d/xml.ini,
/etc/php.d/xml_wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

However, it still throw an error like if the extension was not loaded by a php.ini file.

How can I do ?

**Edit:**

`phpinfo()` displays this: [image]

Comment: Are you getting the error when using the PHP CLI i.e. runing code from the command line or when running code in a web page?

Comment: When I run the code from command line (using `php -f filename.php`) it works. But from the webpage, it doesn't

Comment: There are often 2 `php.ini` files. One for PHP CLI and one for PHP under the web server. Code a quick web page with just this in it `<?php phpinfo();?>` and look at where that is getting its `php.ini` file

Comment: In fact, in this page, there isn't `zip` in the `Registered PHP Streams` row. How to register it ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly moreover, ` /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d/40-zip.ini` is registred in `Additional .ini files parsed` and it contains `extension=zip.so`. I really don't understand.

Comment: which web server you are using?

Comment: If zip extension is loaded correctly (not just the ini, but the .so), you will find a Zip section in phpinfo before the "Additional Modules" section. Then you have the Zip, Zip version and Libzip version. The .ini file can be loaded, but the .so will generate an error if not found inside the server log (with display_startup_errors = On). PHP will check with the extension_dir value to load zip.so.

Comment: THe `php.ini` for the web site is `etc/opt/rem/php71/php.ini` check that one for the zip extension

Comment: @progysm In fact, there is no `Zip` section in phpinfo before `Additionnal Modules`

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is nothing about `zip` in this file, but there also are nothing about the other extensions.

Comment: Check that extension_dir value (in your php.ini) points to the folder with all .so files.

Comment: @progysm I just did this, `local value` is `/opt/remi/php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules` and `master value` is `/opt/remi/php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules
`. In both directories, there is a zip.so file

Comment: What about the error log, with display_startup_errors = On (you need to restart the server) ? I find it weird that it create /etc/opt/remi/php71 and /opt/remi/php71/, but I guess it's from your ./configure command.